# Windows 7 64 Bit Pro fails to install

Tags: windows-7, installation, dvd

I am having a strange error and cant find much information on it.  I am trying to use a Dell Windows 7 Pro 64 bit DVD to install Windows on a Dell desktop.  Installation runs up until the point where the text based grey and white bar rolls across the bottom of the screen and says "Windows is loading files" or something close to that.  However, once the white bar finishes, it just hangs forever.  Just for giggles, I tried a Dell XP CD and it worked fine.  Mint 64 bit and Ubuntu 64 bit installed as well.  Its just Dell's Windows 7 Pro 64 bit DVDs - I tried 2 of them in case one DVD was bad.

Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like it's installing, but its just failing to boot the first time?

Comment: @Keltari (I believe you have checked, but) Does a partition you are installling Win 7 on have at least 20Gb of memory - required for Win 7 installation?

Comment: @Wlad Yes, its a 160GB HDD, single partition.  In one attempt I preformatted it to NTFS, just in case.  No luck.

Comment: @Keltari Another installation way you can try is to install Windows from USB or external HDD.

Comment: Does the Dell desktop meets the minimum requirements for 64-bit Windows 7 Pro? What was the original OS?

Answer (score 0):

I should have known.  I didnt follow the advice I give others:  Whenever Windows fails to install, run a memory check.  I assumed since I had no (visible) issues with Mint installed, and installing other versions of Windows, that the memory was fine.  However, running Memtest86 showed memory errors... sigh.